# Python class inheritance, add to init

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a class:

```
class indentity_resolve():

    def __init__(self,
                 pii_combined_location,
                 block_col,
                 cores,
                 comparison_file_location):


        self.pii_combined_location = pii_combined_location
        self.block_col = block_col
        self.cores = cores
        self.comparison_file_location = comparison_file_location
```

I want to setup a similar class that inherits from this but adds and extra input. I've read similar examples but haven't been able to get it to work. Here's my attempted:

```
class indentity_resolve_delta(indentity_resolve):

    def __init__(self, resolved_pii_location_block):

        super().__init__()
        self.resolved_pii_location_block = resolved_pii_location_block
```

I get the error `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pii_combined_location'`. It's probably and easy fix but I just can't get it right.

Comment: Your subclass doesn't accept any of the arguments that the parent class does. It also doesn't pass any when it calls the parent `__init__`.

Comment: How would I add it so?

Comment: Well, how did you add those arguments to the parent?

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly take all the arguments you need in the subclass initialiser, and pass them through to the superclass, by using args and kwargs:

```py
class indentity_resolve_delta(indentity_resolve):

    def __init__(self, resolved_pii_location_block, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.resolved_pii_location_block = resolved_pii_location_block
```

For more info about args and kwargs:
[*args **kwargs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters)